# Maximum JDK version supported for apache spark 2.4.5.1

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

Can someone please let me know the maximum JDK version supported for
Apache spark 2.4.5.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check [documentation for Spark 2.4.5](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.5/), then you see following description:

> Spark runs on **Java 8**, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x).

The first version that supports Java 11 is Spark 3.0.